# Linter for Google shell style guide?

Tags: flycheck, bash, style

Does anyone know of a Bash linter for the [Google shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml)? I have been using shellcheck as my linter with flycheck but it doesn't conform to this standard.

Comment: Is this question about the linter itself, or `flycheck`?  If the former, it's not really an Emacs question, and we should migrate the post to a sister site.

Comment: I'm asking if anyone knows of something that specifically will work in Emacs - I used flycheck as an example for the package I use to handle linting but if another package would handle it that is fine too.

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask the question in other place, since it is about Shell, not Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shfmt](https://github.com/mvdan/sh) to format shell/bash code. It is configurable, so you should be able to get the Google style with something like `shfmt -i 2 -ci`.

It's a standalone tool, but it should be easy enough to integrate with editors and IDEs. There are plugins for vim, atom, and vscode already.